# How can I get ArgoCD to deploy an application for each feature branch for any git provider?

Tags: git, git-flow, argocd

I have installed ArgoCD v2.6.5 using the Helm chart [here](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm), version `5.27.0`.

Our team uses `feature/` branches to perform independent development work, before merging to `develop`, and then `main`. This broadly follows git-flow.

While developing Helm charts, it would be really useful if we could use ArgoCD to continuously monitor all feature branches of our git repository, and deploy these to separate namespaces.

Ideally, I would like this to happen in an automated fashion, solely triggered by ArgoCD.

The developer workflow would look something like this:

- When a new `feature/*` branch is pushed to `origin`, a new `Application` is created, which tracks the feature branch, and is deployed to a new namespace based on the feature branch name.
- When a `feature/*` branch is closed, the `Application` should be deleted.

I have looked into `ApplicationSets`, more specifically the [Git generator](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/applicationset/Generators-Git/), and the [SCM Provider generator](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/applicationset/Generators-SCM-Provider/).

Neither fulfil the requirement as far as I can tell:

- The Git generator only mentions `revision`, but no branch filtering or templating ability based on the revision
- The SCM Provider generator `automatically discover[s] repositories within an organization`, which is too high-level. It does have `allBranches` and `branchMatch` but these run on **all** repositories for an org in an SCM provider, and is also constrained to only those particular SCM providers.

Is is possible to scan a single git repository, fetch only the `feature/*` branches, and create `Applications` for each (deleting once the branch is closed)? Preferrably with an automated ArgoCD synchronisation, like `ApplicationSet` generators.